# Recompiling functions in Clojure Repl cause compiler warning

Tags: clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, figwheel

I seem to not know some important aspects of REPLs, using `figwheel` or `lein-autoreload`.

If I start a REPL using one of the mentioned plugins and do changes on one of the project files, I usually get compiler warnings. Often, this means I have to restart the REPL, which defeats the whole purpose of those plugins.

Let me give you an example. I have three files: `core.cljs`, `demoscene.cljs` and `objects.cljs`. They reference each other in the order I mentioned them using e.g. `(:require [ns.demoscene :as demoscene])`. My main function is located in `core.cljs`.
I start a figwheel REPL using `lein figwheel`, start my browser, everything works fine.
If I edit a function in `objects.cljs` and save the changes, I get a compiler warning:

```
Compile Warning src/cljs/ns/demoscene.cljs
update already refers to: cljs.core/update being replaced by: ns.demoscene/update
```

This is really odd on more than one level:

1. I didn't edit `demoscene.cljs`
2. Why should `cljs.core/update` be replaced by `ns.demoscene/update`
3. If I reload the site (I do not restart the figwheel session), everything is fine again. My changes are applied etc.

Can you tell me, what is happening in the background? What am I missing to understand this situation? What do I have to do to avoid these warnings?

Please tell me if you need any more resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I didn't edit `demoscene.cljs`

I think this might be reloaded because it's required by the file you did edit: `core.cljs`.

> Why should `cljs.core/update` be replaced by `ns.demoscene/update`

You'll see this warning whenever you define a function of the same name as a `core` namespace function, because those `core` functions are always available by default in your namespaces. The warning is telling you any call to `update` in that namespace will *not* be `cljs.core/update`; it will be the `update` function you defined in your namespace. You can explicitly [exclude](https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/refer-clojure) any `core` functions that you want to "overshadow" in your namespace e.g. `(:refer-clojure :exclude [update])`

Comment: The other thing worth mentioning is that what the OP is seeing are warnings and not errors.  While it is important to understand what a warning means, it is also worth emphasising that it is a warning and not an error. As you have pointed out, the warning is about redefinition of core functions and as pointed out in the other response, generally not a good idea unless you have a genuine need/reason to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be honest, I didn't know that such core functions exist, although, now that I read the warning again, it becomes clear. I feel so stupid now...

Answer (score 3):

Taylor is correct, but I would like to add that in practice, I have found it to be a bad idea to shadow core functions. It tends to lead to fair bit of time wasted when you've:

1. done this
2. forgot that you did that (might be an hour later, might be months, might not even be you)
3. attempt to use the core function in another part of the file

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I completely agree with you, that shadowing is a bad practice. I renamed by functions accordingly.